# Callback for when a connection is established in Paho

Tags: java, mqtt

I'm using the Eclipse MQTT library Paho and I can't find a way to decide when the clients connection to the broker has been established. *Does anyone know if there is a way to do this currently?*

I can't seem to find any information about this in the MqttCallback class in the documentation nor can I find a bug or feature request of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client has a method that returns the status of the connection, if that is what you are looking for

```
 public class MQTT_Client implements MqttCallback {

 private MqttClient mqtt;

 public boolean connect(){
    try{
       mqtt = new MqttClient(....);
       ....
       mqtt.connect();
       //Connected
       return true;
    catch(MqttException e){
       //Connection failed
       return false;
    }
 }

 @Override
public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
    //Connection Lost
}
```

This method can be used to check connection status:

```
 boolean connected = mqtt.isConnected();
```

Comment: I was hoping for an event, but I guess polling with the above might do it...?

Comment: Have you looked at MQTTAsyncClient in the newest version of the Paho code? If you would like to raise a bug on Eclipse Bugzilla we can address your issue there either in the docs or in the code. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the post, you can see the points where connection status can be changed, this should be enough imo

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I thought the MqttClient.connect() was asynchronous, seems I was wrong... I've misunderstood my issue. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Checking the current connection status is not the same as having a connection established callback. The state transitions are interesting. Having a connection_lost callback and not a connection_made callback seems odd in the context of auto-reconnect.